# Alerting after resizing an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I put an alert message just after am done re-sizing an element? That is, after the element has been re-sized.
resizeend() method not working.

Comment: can u add the code as well.

Comment: here:http://jsfiddle.net/93cyr/

Answer (score 1):

check below link with

```
$( $clone ).resizable({

                stop:function(){
                     hello();
                },

            });
```

check below link for more , which uses jquery ui for resizing and invoking javascrip after resize occurs

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lm9C3/1/)

html content

```
<div class = "resizethis">
resize this widget
```

two js libraries

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

one css

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

javascript content

```
$('.resizethis').resizable({
stop: resizestopped
});

function resizestopped(){
    alert('resize stopped');
}
```

css

```
.resizethis{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 2px solid red;
}
```